# Peskin and Schroeder perturbative calculation of anomaly

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, correlation-functions, quantum-anomalies

On page 661 Peskin and Schroeder calculates the ABJ anomaly pertubatively. The book gives the ABJ anomly as

$$\tag{19.45}\partial_\mu j^{\mu 5}=-\frac{e^2}{16\pi^2}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F_{\mu\nu}.$$

However when the book goes on to check (19.45), it only checks on page 664

$$\tag{19.60} \langle p,k|\partial_\mu j^{\mu 5}(0)|0\rangle=-\frac{e^2}{16\pi^2}\langle p,k|\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F_{\mu\nu}(0)|0\rangle.$$

My question is: (19.60) of course doesn't imply (19.45), as we only checked $x=0$ and the matrix element connecting $\langle p,k|$ and $|0\rangle$. How can Peskin and Schroeder claim (19.45) is checked?